# How to efficiently left join in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables - one with all user_ids and their attributes, and another one of only interesting user_ids and their attributes. I'd like to query them both to create a training set for a machine learning problem.

In pure SQL I'd do it like this:

```sql
select label, user_id, feature 
from (
   select 1 as label, user_id, feature
   from interesting_table

   UNION ALL

   select 0 as label, a.user_id, a.feature
   from alldata_table a
   left join
   interesting table b
   on a.user_id = b.user_id
   where b.user_id is null
)
```

In Spark, pulling from `interesting_table` is easy enough, but the left join between `interesting_table` and `alldata_table` is proving expensive. Should I

- Do the operation exactly as above in sql and then extract the result as a data frame?
- Create `interesting_table` and `alldata_table` as data frames and use the .join() operator?
- Create `interesting_table` and `alldata_table` as data frames, get unique members of `interesting_df.user_id` and subset `alldata_df.user_id` by negating '.isin()'?
- Something else?

Comment: Wait,  `a.user_id = b.user_id` and `where b.user_id is null`, so there could be only `where a.user_id is null`.

Comment: It's a left join, so if b.user_id is null and a.user_id is not, then you retain a.user_id and it signifies a mismatch.

Comment: sorry, my fault ;) It's okey. I will write more expensive answer, however first tought is that there is no matter if you use DSL or SQL - both of them are optimized using Catalyst optimizer

Comment: That's probably true, I'm hoping that there's another way of thinking altogether and that I'm formulating the problem in a needlessly inefficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive this is the best answer, but I ended up using the dataframe API with a broadcast.

```
alldata_table = spark.table('alldata_table')
interesting_table = spark.table('interesting_table')
interesting_table.withColumnRenamed('user_id','user_id_interesting')

new_table = alldata_table.join(broadcast(interesting_table),
  cond=[alldata_table['user_id']==interesting_table['user_id_interesting']],
  how='left_outer')
new_table.filter(new_table['user_id_interesting'].isnull())
```

Of course this assumes `interesting_table` is small enough to broadcast. Presumably it could be reduced to only the `user_id` field to make it smaller.